# how do i select an array element in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, indexing, numbers

how do i select an array element with the number input?

Lets say I have:

```
var images=["http://blogs.independent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/google-zip.jpg",
        "http://www.quantumseolabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/google1.jpg"];
```

How do I select an image to be displayed or another with the number input?

When the number changes so does the link.

thx

Comment: You mean like `var myImage = images[parseInt(myInput.value,10)]` ?

Comment: i mean like when the number in the input box changes so does the image

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="myInput" value="0" />
<div id="imgWrp"></div>
```

You could do something like this:

```
var images = ['/img/1.jpg','/img/2.jpg'];

$('#myInput').on('change', function(event) {
  var myInputVal = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (images[myInputVal]) {
    $('#imgWrp').html('<img src="' + images[myInputVal] + ' />');      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `input` and `img` selectors and you should be good to go:

```
var images = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg'];

$('input').on('change', function(event) {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    $('img').attr('src', images[fieldValue]);
});
```